# What is the domain of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have this function

$$
f(x) \triangleq \int_{x}^{2x}\dfrac{\cos t}{t}dt.
$$

How to prove that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$?

$\cos t$ is equivalent $1$ in $0$ so I have $1/t$ which is not defined in $0$.

Comment: $f$ is a function of $x$ not $t$.

Comment: You could define $\;f(0)=\int_0^0\frac{\cos t}tdt\;$ ...or simply $\;f(0)=0\;$ .

Comment: The integral of $1/t$ is not defined in $0$.

Comment: @Chiba The integral is defined from zero to zero...who cares then what the integrand is? But it doesn't matter: just define the value of the function as zero in zero and we're done.